# stretching one item in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with a variable number of items. When there is to few items to fill the entire screen, then i want background inside the footer to stretch all the way to the imageview in the bottom of screen. How can i achieve that?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/savings_details_activity_layout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/default_list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:listSelector="@color/transparent" />

  <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/action_bar_background"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

List items

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_10dp"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_10dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_item_value"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/header_image"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_header"
        style="@style/LargeTextWhiteWithShadow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="header" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_sub_header"
        style="@style/SmallTextLightBlueWithShadow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="sub header" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_value"
    style="@style/LargeTextWhiteWithShadow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="value"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have a listview footer which is just an image. I do not care if i stretch the listview footer or the last item in the list.

Comment: do you want you imageView at the background if you have a lot of items, or exaclty what ?

Comment: in other word i want to align the footer in my list with the bottom_bar(imageview) if there is "air" between the list and the bottom_bar

Comment: @Houcine the bottom_bar is working as it should, i just want the footer in my list to stretch down to the bottom_bar when the list is short

Comment: for example when you have just 3 items on your list ,you want that the image view will be just below the last item of your list , and not at the bottom , is that what you wan't ?

Comment: when the list is short , and you imageView is at the bottom , you cant stretch the last item of your list in order to be just above the footer if that's what you want to do

Comment: @Houcine the last one is correct. i want to stretch the last item to be just above my ImageView footer

Comment: you can't do that, you can just display the background of your listView just above the footer ( imageView ) , items are added automatically one after one , so you can't controll each item to display it at the bottom of your list ,

Answer (score 1):

Consider using layout:weight. You should definetely be able to achieve using weights.

More information http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#linearlayout